# Can color of points above a threshold vary smoothly, in ggplot2?

Tags: r

I created the following plot in `R`

```
p_cd = c(0.01,0.15,0.5,0.7,0.9)
p_cr = c(0.01,0.15,0.5,0.7,0.9)

data = as.data.frame(expand.grid(p_cd,p_cr))
data = cbind(data,rep(NA,dim(data)[1]))
colnames(data) = c('p_cd','p_cr','weights')
weights = runif(sum(seq(1,4,by=1)),0,5)
u = 1
for(i in 1:dim(data)[1]){
  if(data[i,1]>data[i,2]){
    data[i,3] = weights[u]
    u = u + 1
  }
}

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data[!is.na(data[,3]),], aes(x=p_cd, y=p_cr, color=weights, size = 3)) +
  geom_point() + scale_size_continuous(name = NULL)
```

I would like to ask if there is a way to make all the points who correspond to `weights < 1` dark blue and then the points `weights > = 1` to have there color increase smoothly from light blue to a more light blue color?

What I mean is to but a threshold on the color, i.e. `weights <1` correspond to really dark blue whereas `weights >= 1`  can have that smooth scale of color based on their intensity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like

```
library(tidyverse)

p_cd = c(0.01,0.15,0.5,0.7,0.9)
p_cr = c(0.01,0.15,0.5,0.7,0.9)

data = as.data.frame(expand.grid(p_cd,p_cr))
data = cbind(data,rep(NA,dim(data)[1]))
colnames(data) = c('p_cd','p_cr','weights')
weights = runif(sum(seq(1,4,by=1)),0,5)
u = 1
for(i in 1:dim(data)[1]){
  if(data[i,1]>data[i,2]){
    data[i,3] = weights[u]
    u = u + 1
  }
}

ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = subset(data, weights > 1), aes(x=p_cd, y=p_cr, col = weights), size = 3) +
  scale_color_continuous(type = "viridis") +
  geom_point(data = subset(data, weights < 1), aes(x=p_cd, y=p_cr), color = "dark blue", size = 3)
```

[image]